# How to get from Kreuzberg to Schönefeld

Tags: public-transport, germany, berlin

Can anyone help with any information on which SBahn or bus to take from the Kreuzberg area of Berlin on the 8th August around 7:00am to Schönefeld airport?

Also is it worth buying the 72-hour Berlin Welcome card for travel (and sightseeing), which I think might include the zone for the airport?

Comment: When I lived in Berlin and needed to go to SXF I would just put it into Google maps. Very accurate information for regional trains and S-Bahn.

Answer (score 8):

Kreuzberg is a big area and the quickest route depends on your starting destination. I'd advise you to check the best route for yourself here https://www.bvg.de/en but the SBahn that goes to Schönefeld is the S9.

Buying the 72h version is up to you and your need for public transport. When you take a subway or bus more than 5 times a day, it is already cheaper to get the 72h ticket. Also, the 72h ticket gives you a discount on entry fees for many museums.

Schönefeld is in the C-Area of Berlin's public transport provider BVG, so you should buy the ABC-version, of the tourist ticket, even though you will need it only for the fare to Schönefeld.

Comment: Welcome Nils Ole, I do appreciate your answer. (+1)

Comment: Note: It is slightly cheaper to buy the AB WelcomeCard, and an extension ticket on the way to and from the airport, than to buy the ABC WelcomeCard.